# Ramification in cyclotomic extension

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I am trying to understand how primes ramify in $\mathbb Q(\zeta _p)/\mathbb Q$ for $p$ prime. From class field theory, how a prime $q$ ramifies depends only on $q \mod p$.
I have following particular question in mind:

> Which primes have inertia degree $f=6$ in $\mathbb Q (\zeta _{31}) /\mathbb Q?$

We know that $(31)$ totally ramifies and all other primes are unramified. For these unramified primes, their Frobenius element generates the Decomposition group which has size $f$ (as $e=1$). Frobenius of $q$ acts as $\zeta _{31} \mapsto \zeta _{31} ^q$. So we look for $q$ such that $\zeta _{31} ^{q^6} =1$ i.e. primes such that $q^6 =1 \mod 31$. Finding solutions to $x^6=1\mod 31$ seems difficult though with help of computer I have found that elements of order $6$ in $(\mathbb Z/31 \mathbb Z)^\times$ are $6$ and $26$. So primes which are $6 \text{ or } 26 \mod 31$ have inertia degree in $\mathbb Q (\zeta _{31}) /\mathbb Q$. Some examples are $37,181,223,347,367,409,491$.

But this seems very difficult as it requires dealing with $(\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z)^\times$. Is there any way to simplify my work above?
I was told that this question can be answered using Dirichlet characters. How do Dirichlet characters help us? I know that we need to find primes such that $$\frac{|\{\chi : (\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z)^\times \rightarrow \mathbb C ^\times \ | \ \chi (q) \neq 0\}|}{| \{\chi : (\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z)^\times \rightarrow \mathbb C ^\times \ | \ \chi (q) = 1\}|}=6 $$
but this looks difficult too for it requires knowledge of the Dirichlet characters group.

Is there an easy answer to this question and can I generalize?
Please feel free to provide any reference, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not the right guy to post an answer, so I restrict myself to a few comments. You know by general theory that $(\Bbb{Z}/31\Bbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order $31-1=30=5\cdot6$. This means that every fifth power in it is a solution of $x^6=1$. For example $2^5\equiv1$ (not much there) and $3^5=243\equiv-5\equiv 26$, bingo! You then get others as powers of $-5$ and can verfy that $-5$ is a primitive root of order six.

Comment: So the sentiment might also be that you should be delighted to get a way with dealing with $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*$ only, when the splitting behavior ($e$, $f$ and $g$) can be determined by studying that group alone. Class field theory says that grouping primes into residue classes (modulo a carefully chosen modulus $m$) describe the splitting behavior of primes in an extension $K/\Bbb{Q}$ if and only if $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is an abelian Galois extension. Which (by the so called Kronecker-Weber theorem) happens if and only if $K$ is a subfield of some cyclotomic field.

Comment: (cont'd) Delving into class field theory takes serious effort. I bring this up mostly to make you **appreciate** these cases where you get away with simple calculations like this. It quickly becomes hairy, when we leave the realm of abelian extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comments. My point was though it is possible to somehow manage the situation for $p=31$, we resorted to brute force methods. These calculations will become incredibly difficult, I imagine, as $p$ increases. Class field theory tells us that we should be able to solve this problem for $\mathbb Q(\zeta _n) /\mathbb Q$ in general, which would be even harder. So far in my calculations I have not used any CFT and want to know can we find an efficient solution, which works for other cases as well, using advanced tools.